# Why the file with a current datetime uploaded to S3 with docker has one hour difference than the actual time?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, datetime, amazon-s3

I have a Python script that runs in docker to append a current datetime to the file.

When I tested the script in IntelliJ, the file has the right datetime, but when I tested it with docker, the file will have one hour difference than the actual time, what did I do wrong: Or this is something with AWS or docker?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a time zone issue. Verify that S3, your system and the docker container all agree on the time zone they're using (or set them all to GMT/Zulu).

Also, what time was it in your locale when you created those files? Was it 10:57 local time? It could also be an issue of the display (i.e. how do you access those files to check their date and time).

I suspect your system is set to local time, but with Universal time zone (i.e. it is actually one to two hours off; when it says "10:57", you think it means "10:57 local", while it is actually running on 10:57 Zulu, i.e. 12:57 local).

You probably want to look at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes).

Comment: For example my local time (also the time on my machine is 13:00), when I upload the file to S3 on IntelliJ, it will be 13:00 as well. But if I tested with docker, it will be 12:00. If it's a time zone problem, does it mean we don't need to fix it.

Comment: It's always best to keep things synchronized. I added a link you'll probably find useful.